# Не присоединяется домен к сайту

Tags: домен

Сайт сделан на Google-сайтах, домен куплен в Network Solution (куплен не мною, а нужно присоединить именно этот. С другими провайдерами проблем не было). Итак, что сделано:
 - подтвердил право собственности на домен с помощью TXT-записи.
 - успешно присоединил домен в настройках гугл сайта.
 - забиваю в командной строке ping www.site.com - выводится IP, всё как положено, и скорость загрузки сайта показывает. 
  Но вот беда: вводишь адрес сайта в адресную строку - и никого! В чём может быть проблема? Я сделал уже с десяток сайтов в гугл-конструкторе, но с таким сталкиваюсь впервые! Помогите.

Comment: Почистите кэш, перезапустите браузер?

Comment: уже всё перепробовал. Очевидно, что проблема на стороне провайдера домена. Но - как?

Comment: только что пришло системное сообщение на гугл-сайте о том, что "неправильная конфигурация DNS". Что это может быть? Я добавил только CNAME: www - ghs.googlehosted.com  То есть, всё делал, как обычно.